# Having trouble with pyserial

Tags: python, pyserial

I've been trying to communicate with [a piece of machinery](https://mark-10.com/downloads/product-downloads/manualESM303.pdf).
I verified the COM port and baud rate and 8N1 setup and open port, etc. using manual CMD.
The manual indicates to use `\` for start byte and `/` for end byte of telegram.

When I run it basically just hangs up, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```py
import serial char
ser = serial.Serial('COM6' , 115200)
ser.is_open
ser.write(b'\p/')
s = ser.read(9)
print(s)
```

[image: Code]

Comment: First, where does it hang?  Second, according to section 6.2.1, the correct command is "/p\".

Answer (score 1):

You could try it out this way. I don't have a device to verify it

```py
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM6' , 115200)

if ser.isOpen(): # Check is Serial is Open
    ser.write(b'\p/') # Write to Serial
    sleep(2) # Sleep for 2 seconds
    s = ser.read(9) # Read from Serial
else:
   print("Serial is not open")
```

Answer (score 0):

From the manual it shows the returned codes for the "p" command as one or two characters. If you are trying to read 9 bytes with no timeout set it will hang until 9 bytes are received. Try using **ser.read_all()** after a short delay.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly helpful = Saiprasad Balasubramanian + Mike67 + Bukzor + SuzukiBKing
I was successful with your advice.  I plan to add the conditional later, thx SB ;).

```
    import serial
    import time
    ser = serial.Serial('COM6' , 115200)
    ser.write(bytearray([47, 112, 92]))
    time.sleep(2)
    s = ser.read_all()
    print(s)
```